# Unable to find a specification for `GoogleUtilities-Environment-Logger-NSData+zlib`

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods

I have been working successfully with the flutter when a few weeks backed I updated Flutter like I always do whenever an update is available.  And now I can't run Flutter because of the following error:

[!] Unable to find a specification for `GoogleUtilities-Environment-Logger-NSData+zlib`

This seems like a gem Cocoapods error.  But I didn't just recently install or update Cocoapods.
I didn't update or install Ruby or Gem.

It was suggested I add a reference to GoogleUtilities in my project's Podfile:
"pod 'GoogleUtilities/Environment/Logger/NSData+zlib'".  but has no affect.

The following is suggested:

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

I really don't understand why I am being led down a rabbithole because I decided updated Flutter. I've been working with Flutter for almost a year without any major issues.  And now this.  It's very frustrating.

Are there any directions/recipes out there I can follow to reestablish my Flutter dev environment from scratch?  For example, my Cocoapods was already installed via Ruby gems.  But not by me.  Should I use Homebrew?

'Which pod' resolves to /usr/local/bin/pod.  But gem cocoapods appear to be coming from a different location:  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods.  This is all so confusing.

I tried all sorts of things:
Flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod repo update
pod install --repo-update
which pod
gem --version
pod --version
pod install

Added "pod 'GoogleUtilities/Environment/Logger/NSData+zlib'" to my project's Podfile.